# Moving data from worksheet 1 to a new worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hope you all are well and had a lovely xmas break and new years!

I am trying to create a VBA code to move a data dump in Excel (extracted from PowerBI), to seperate new worksheets.
So for example, below:
[Data dump example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYTCz.png)

if the Security Description, is the same, then all rows in the data dump to be copy and pasted into a new worksheet.

So the end result would be:
Worksheet 1: Data Dump

Worksheet 2: All the rows from data dump which have Security Description "Security 1 - Description 1"

Worksheet 3: All the rows from data dump which have Security Description "Security 1 - Description 2"

Worksheet 4: All the rows from data dump which have Security Description "Security 2 - Description 1"

And so on for each unique Security Description.

Can somebody please help on this?

Thank you!
Best,

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it:

1. Store your data as an array.  Let's call it `OriginalArray`.
2. Create a new array for each combination of Security Description, Fund Name, Pool Name that you have.
3. Iterate through all of the rows in `OriginalArray` and populate the respective arrays that you just created with the appropriate rows of data.
4. Once the iteration is complete, write all of the arrays where you need them in your different worksheets.

I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do exactly, but even so, this should hopefully be enough to guide you.

Comment: Thank you! I've never used arrays before so I'll need to research that.
The aim is
1. Extract data into excel
2. If the security description, fund name and pool name are the same: copy those rows onto a new worksheet (ask the macro to open a new worksheet)

There would be 100s of rows with the same security description, fund name and pool name - but different investment balance values.

But also there would be numerous different security descriptions and pool name.
The extract will have the same fund name in the data dump.

Any example code would be awesome. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you mean that the content in Security Description, Fund Name, and Pool name are the same as each other?

Comment: Nope, so security description, fund name and pool name are different.
It's that Security description can show up multiple times in that column.
So if that row has the same security description then copy and paste those rows into a new worksheet.
The end result would be each worksheet would have the rows for 1 'Security Description'
So worksheet 1 = data dump.
Worksheet 2 = All rows from data dump with the same 'Security Description' (say description 'XXX'
worksheet 3 = All rows from data dump with another same security description (say security description 'YYY')

Comment: Okay, I understand now.  Fortunately, the methodology will be the same as my answer above.  You will make a series of checks against each row in your array, and whenever a row is a match to one of those checks, you'll do whatever is appropriate for that check.

Comment: Thank you! I'll research arrays and give it a go now.